# Text of manuscript of Ben Ish Chai found after Saddam Hussein’s downfall in 2003?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-shelach, behaalotcha-parsha, manuscripts

I heard in a shiur about manuscripts of the Ben Ish Chai found by American troops among 2,700 seforim and tens of thousands of Jewish documents in a flooded basement of Iraq’s intelligence headquarters after Saddam Hussein’s downfall in 2003 (see [here](http://matzav.com/new-sefer-of-the-ben-ish-chai-printed-from-manuscript-found-in-saddam-husseins-intelligence-offices/)) .

In particular he wrote about the connection between the loshon hora of Miriam in Behaalotecha and the sin of the spies in Shelach. The normal punishment for loshon hora is leprosy and that was not the punishment of the spies. The  Ben Ish Chai suggests that the common factor is not loshon hora but lack of respect for Moshe.

Has anyone seen either the text of this  Ben Ish Chai or a write-up of the dvar Torah please?

Comment: Related: [ostensible recovered manuscripts](https://ija.archives.gov/search/Ben%20ish)

Comment: He actually has quite a bit of nice looking long pieces on Parashat Shelach. I don't know which one it is, but I'll write up what I can once I go through it. Thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

The sefer is called Bircas Hareyach and can be bought [here](http://mysefer.com/Hebrew/Rabbi-Yosef-Chaim-Ben-Ish-Chai/Birkat-HaReyach---Rabbi-Yosef-Chaim-2-vol.__p-73-183-8990.aspx)

Comment: Does that answer the question?